# jquery mobile finger(s) detection

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile, multi-touch, swipe

With jquery mobile, is it possible to detect the number of fingers that are on the screen? I am an UI student trying to put together an application for a school project. Essentially I need to have a different feedback for one, two and three finger swipe but I am not sure on how jquery mobile or TouchSwipe plug-in do detection.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

[jQuery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b3/docs/api/events.html) (as of version 1.03b) only supports basic swipes, and does not distinguish between 1, 2, and 3 fingers.

[touchSwipe](http://labs.skinkers.com/touchSwipe/) (as of version 1.2.4) does support multi-finger swipes by passing in a `finger` option, however, the options are limited to either 1 or 2 fingers.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there is currently no support for multiple fingers in jquery mobile and last time i checked TouchSwipe, it didn't feature that either. But there is another plugin - jQuery Multiswipe that should support multiple fingers. http://plugins.jquery.com/project/multiswipe